# load tibble give an error: “check_dots_used”

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, ellipsis

Im tried to load starwars data in *dplyr* packages and shows:

```
>starwars
Error in check_dots_used(action = warn) : unused argument (action = warn)
```

I already update *tidyverse* and *ellipsis* but still shows the same error

Comment: Did you Restart R and tried again?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, but with all tibbles.

A workaround is to transform the dataset to a data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(dplyr::starwars)
```